# How do I use template<typename> in c++

Tags: c++, templates

I am implementing an AVL tree and trying to understand how template works so I can store different types of data in my tree. Right now I can only store int, but I'd like to be able to store other types if I need to. How would I use template for this?

Right now this is the class I have:

```
struct Avlnode{
int data;
int balfact;
Avlnode *left;
Avlnode *right;
};

class Avltree{
public:
Avltree();
~Avltree( );
Avlnode* insert(int i, bool* j);
static Avlnode* buildtree ( Avlnode *root, int data, bool *h ) ;
void display( Avlnode *root );
Avlnode* deldata ( Avlnode* root, int data, bool *h );
static Avlnode* del ( Avlnode *node, Avlnode* root, bool *h );
static Avlnode* balright ( Avlnode *root, bool *h );
static Avlnode* balleft ( Avlnode* root, bool *h );
void setroot ( Avlnode *avl );
static void deltree ( Avlnode *root );
private:
Avlnode *root;
int items;
};
```

And they are defined:

```
Avltree::Avltree( ){
root = NULL;
items = 0;
}

Avlnode* Avltree::insert( int data, bool *h ){
root = buildtree( root, data, h );
return root;
}

Avlnode* Avltree::buildtree( Avlnode *root, int data, bool *h ){
Avlnode *node1, *node2;

if( root == NULL ){
    root = new Avlnode;
    root -> data = data;
    root -> left = NULL;
    root -> right = NULL;
    root -> balfact = 0;
    *h = true;
    return( root );
}
if ( data < root -> data ){
    root -> left = buildtree( root -> left, data, h );

    // If left subtree is higher
    if( *h ){
        switch ( root -> balfact ){
            case 1:
                node1 = root -> left;
                if ( node1 -> balfact == 1 ){
                    //cout << "\nRight rotation.";
                    root -> left = node1 -> right;
                    node1 -> right = root;
                    root -> balfact = 0;
                    root = node1;
                }
                else{
                    //cout << "\nDouble rotation, left then right." ;
                    node2 = node1 -> right;
                    node1 -> right = node2 -> left;
                    node2 -> left = node1;
                    root -> left = node2 -> right;
                    node2 -> right = root;
                    if ( node2 -> balfact == 1 )
                        root -> balfact = -1;
                    else
                        root -> balfact = 0;
                    if ( node2 -> balfact == -1 )
                        node1 -> balfact = 1;
                    else
                        node1 -> balfact = 0;
                    root = node2;
                }
                root -> balfact = 0;
                *h = false;
                break;

            case 0:
                root -> balfact = 1;
                break;
            case -1:
                root -> balfact = 0;
                *h = false;
        }
    }
}

if ( data > root -> data ){
    root -> right = buildtree ( root -> right, data, h );

    if ( *h ){
        switch ( root -> balfact ){
            case 1:
                root -> balfact = 0;
                *h = false;
                break;
            case 0:
                root -> balfact = -1;
                break;
            case -1:
                node1 = root -> right;
                if ( node1 -> balfact == -1 ){
                    //cout << "\nLeft rotation.";
                    root -> right = node1 -> left;
                    node1 -> left = root;
                    root -> balfact = 0;
                    root = node1;
                }
                else{
                    //cout << "\nDouble rotation, right then left.";
                    node2 = node1 -> left;
                    node1 -> left = node2 -> right;
                    node2 -> right = node1;
                    root -> right = node2 -> left;
                    node2 -> left = root;
                    if ( node2 -> balfact == -1 )
                        root -> balfact = 1;
                    else
                        root -> balfact = 0;
                    if ( node2 -> balfact == 1 )
                        node1 -> balfact = -1;
                    else
                        node1 -> balfact = 0;
                    root = node2;
                }
                root -> balfact = 0;
                *h = false;
        }
    }
}
return ( root );
}

void Avltree::display ( Avlnode* root ){
if ( root != NULL ){
    display ( root -> left );
    cout << root -> data << "\t";
    display ( root -> right );
}
}

Avlnode* Avltree::deldata ( Avlnode *root, int data, bool *h ){
Avlnode *node;
if ( root -> data == 13 )
    cout << root -> data ;
if ( root == NULL ){
    //cout << "\nNo such data.";
    return ( root );
}
else{
    if ( data < root -> data ){
        root -> left = deldata ( root -> left, data, h ) ;
        if ( *h )
            root = balright ( root, h ) ;
    }
    else{
        if ( data > root -> data ){
            root -> right = deldata ( root -> right, data, h ) ;
            if ( *h )
                root = balleft ( root, h );
        }
        else{
            node = root;
            if ( node -> right == NULL ){
                root = node -> left ;
                *h = true ;
                delete ( node ) ;
            }
            else{
                if ( node -> left == NULL ){
                    root = node -> right ;
                    *h = true ;
                    delete ( node ) ;
                }
                else{
                    node -> right = del ( node -> right, node, h ) ;
                    if ( *h )
                        root = balleft ( root, h ) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return ( root ) ;
}

Avlnode* Avltree :: del ( Avlnode *succ, Avlnode *node, bool *h ){
Avlnode *temp = succ ;

if ( succ -> left != NULL ){
    succ -> left = del ( succ -> left, node, h ) ;
    if ( *h )
        succ = balright ( succ, h ) ;
}
else{
    temp = succ ;
    node -> data = succ -> data ;
    succ = succ -> right ;
    delete ( temp ) ;
    *h = true ;
}
return ( succ ) ;
}

Avlnode* Avltree :: balright ( Avlnode *root, bool *h ){
Avlnode *temp1, *temp2 ;
switch ( root -> balfact ){
    case 1 :
        root -> balfact = 0 ;
        break ;
    case 0 :
        root -> balfact = -1 ;
        *h  = false ;
        break ;
    case -1 :
        temp1 = root -> right ;
        if ( temp1 -> balfact <= 0 ){
            cout << "\nLeft rotation." ;
            root -> right = temp1 -> left ;
            temp1 -> left = root ;
            if ( temp1 -> balfact == 0 ){
                root -> balfact = -1 ;
                temp1 -> balfact = 1 ;
                *h = false ;
            }
            else{
                root -> balfact = temp1 -> balfact = 0 ;
            }
            root = temp1 ;
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nDouble rotation, right then left." ;
            temp2 = temp1 -> left ;
            temp1 -> left = temp2 -> right ;
            temp2 -> right = temp1 ;
            root -> right = temp2 -> left ;
            temp2 -> left = root ;
            if ( temp2 -> balfact == -1 )
                root -> balfact = 1 ;
            else
                root -> balfact = 0 ;
            if ( temp2 -> balfact == 1 )
                temp1 -> balfact = -1 ;
            else
                temp1 -> balfact = 0 ;
            root = temp2 ;
            temp2 -> balfact = 0 ;
        }
}
return ( root ) ;
}

Avlnode* Avltree::balleft ( Avlnode *root, bool *h ){
Avlnode *temp1, *temp2 ;
switch ( root -> balfact ){
    case -1 :
        root -> balfact = 0 ;
        break ;

    case 0 :
        root -> balfact = 1 ;
        *h = false ;
        break ;

    case 1 :
        temp1 = root -> left ;
        if ( temp1 -> balfact >= 0 ){
            cout << "\nRight rotation." ;
            root -> left = temp1 -> right ;
            temp1 -> right = root ;

            if ( temp1 -> balfact == 0 ){
                root -> balfact = 1 ;
                temp1 -> balfact = -1 ;
                *h = false ;
            }
            else{
                root -> balfact = temp1 -> balfact = 0 ;
            }
            root = temp1 ;
        }
        else{
            cout << "\nDouble rotation, left then right." ;
            temp2 = temp1 -> right ;
            temp1 -> right = temp2 -> left ;
            temp2 -> left = temp1 ;
            root -> left = temp2 -> right ;
            temp2 -> right = root ;
            if ( temp2 -> balfact == 1 )
                root -> balfact = -1 ;
            else
                root -> balfact = 0 ;
            if ( temp2-> balfact == -1 )
                temp1 -> balfact = 1 ;
            else
                temp1 -> balfact = 0 ;
            root = temp2 ;
            temp2 -> balfact = 0 ;
        }
}
return ( root ) ;
}

void Avltree::setroot ( Avlnode *avl ){
root = avl ;
}
Avltree::~Avltree( ){
deltree ( root ) ;
}

void Avltree::deltree ( Avlnode *root ){
if ( root != NULL ){
    deltree ( root -> left ) ;
    deltree ( root -> right ) ;
}
delete ( root ) ;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make `Avlnode` a class template:

```
template<typename T>
struct Avlnode{
  typedef value_type T;
  value_type data;
  value_type balfact;
  Avlnode<T> *left;
  Avlnode<T> *right;
};
```

Then, make `Avltree` a class template:

```
template <typename T>
class Avltree{
public:
typedef T value_type;
typedef node_type Avlnode<T>;
Avltree();
~Avltree( );
node_type* insert(const T& i, bool* j);
static node_type* buildtree ( node_type*root, const T& data, bool *h ) ;
void display( node_type*root );
node_type* deldata ( node_type* root, const T& data, bool *h );
static node_type* del ( node_type* node, node_type* root, bool *h );
....
private:
node_type *root;
T items;
};
```

Then, to instantiate:

```
Avltree<float> treeF;
bool smth = true;
typename AvlTree<float>::node_type* node = treeF.insert(0.5, &smth);
```

Although I would recommend passing the `bools` by reference rather than pointer.